# data table splitting duration based on dates

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, grouping

I have a datatable with 2 columns. One is for timestamp and one is for condition. I am trying to find out the duration for which a condition is occurring. I am able to get the duration. But if my condition is in two days, then I will be getting more than 24 hrs and all.
   I need to split it into respective dates. I am using `rleid` to group and and then I find duration(`max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)` in every group which satisfies the condition. Then I finally `aggregate` it day wise for `sum`).

```
             timestamp  condition
    2020-01-01 10:10:13 0
    2020-01-01 10:11:23 1
    2020-01-01 10:14:45 1
    2020-01-01 11:23:02 1
    2020-01-01 11:33:14 1
    2020-01-01 16:10:13 0
    2020-01-01 18:34:12 1
    2020-01-01 20:10:33 1
    2020-01-01 23:04:56 1
    2020-01-02 10:14:45 1
    2020-01-02 11:23:02 1
    2020-01-02 11:33:14 0
    2020-01-02 16:10:13 0
```

Finding duration when condition is `1`.
Expected output :

```
Date            Duration
2020-01-01      05:52:35
2020-01-02      11:23:02
```

What I am getting when I do grouping and finding duration:

```
 Date            Duration
2020-01-01      18:10:41
```

The problem is with grouping because `rleid` is grouping irrespective of date. Actually if the condition is happening on two days continuously, then it should be limited till 23:59:59 for first day and start from 00:00:00 on second day. This should happen for any number of days.

My code :

```
fdata = data[, group_id := rleid(condition == 1)][]
out = fdata[(condition == 1),][,.(start = as.Date(min(timestamp)),
         duration = as.numeric(max(timestamp) - min(timestamp),units='mins')),by = .((group_id)][,group_id := NULL]
```

Comment: No sorry... actually i was doing a eval parse... I  copied the condition for pasting here.. Now i have corrected it

Comment: I think both will be for same date '2020-01-02'

Comment: I wanted to split the occurance if it exceeds 23:59:59.. The remaining should be under next day and not with the starting day

Comment: This is the final output after converting to hh:mm:ss... I will be getting the duration as fractions initially

Comment: What you got as ouput ?

Comment: Using my code `out[, seconds_to_period(Duration)]#
[1] "5H 52M 35S" "1H 8M 17S"`

Comment: For which day ?  condition 1 is satisfied from `2020-01-01 18:34:12` till `2020-01-02 11:23:02` without any break. But I wanted to split it into two

Comment: But it should be the sum of differences between these : `2020-01-01 11:33:14` and  `2020-01-01 10:11:23` , `2020-01-01 23:59:59` and `2020-01-01 18:34:12`

Comment: I guess you are looking for `as.ITime("10:14:45") + as.ITime("01:08:17")#
[1] "11:23:02"` where `01:08:17` is the difference between the '10:14:45' and '11:23:02

Comment: Yes yes exactly

Comment: Same for the other day also...Instead of 23:04:56 it will be till 23:59:59 because the condition is exceeding to next day

Comment: Ok, it is too late for me. I am deleting the answer, but I did got your logic

Comment: sorry for confusing you in between

Comment: could you please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
DT[, g := rleid(id, as.IDate(timestamp), condition)][
    condition==1L, duration := as.numeric(timestamp[.N] - timestamp[1L], units='secs'), g]

unique(DT, by="g")[condition==1L & duration > 0, .(Duration=sum(duration)), .(id, date=as.IDate(timestamp))]
```

Alternative approach:

```
DT[, g := rleid(id, as.IDate(timestamp), condition)][
    condition==1L, .(id=id[1L], date=as.IDate(timestamp)[1L],
        dft=as.numeric(timestamp[.N] - timestamp[1L], units='secs')), g][
            dft > 0, .(Duration==sum(dft)), .(id, date)]
```

output:

```
   id       date Duration
1:  1 2020-01-01    21155
2:  1 2020-01-02     4097
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("id,timestamp,condition
1,2020-01-01 10:10:13,0
1,2020-01-01 10:11:23,1
1,2020-01-01 10:14:45,1
1,2020-01-01 11:23:02,1
1,2020-01-01 11:33:14,1
1,2020-01-01 16:10:13,0
1,2020-01-01 18:34:12,1
1,2020-01-01 20:10:33,1
1,2020-01-01 23:04:56,1
1,2020-01-02 10:14:45,1
1,2020-01-02 11:23:02,1
1,2020-01-02 11:33:14,0
1,2020-01-02 16:10:13,0")
DT[, timestamp := as.POSIXct(timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %T")]
```

Comment: But it should be the sum of differences between these : `2020-01-01 11:33:14` and  `2020-01-01 10:11:23` , `2020-01-01 23:59:59` and `2020-01-01 18:34:12`

Comment: How to aggregate if I have multiple columns other than date? Like some IDs

Comment: What is `condition==1L`

Comment: What if I have different condition ? Something like a string?

Comment: What is the difference between condition == 1 and condition ==1L ?

Comment: Also how to assign some column name instead of V1  in the ouput?

Comment: What is importance of  `.` ?

Comment: How can I exclude if duration is Zero ?

Comment: `2020-01-01 18:34:12 0
    2020-01-01 20:10:33 1
    2020-01-01 23:04:56 0` here I will get duration as zero because `2020-01-01 20:10:33 - 2020-01-01 20:10:33` is zero. I need to exclude these. If I have only oen day daya, I may get sum as zero for that day. I dont need a entry that is meaning kess

Comment: Yes If I have only one data point on that day, Then it will show

Comment: have added another condition

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` on the 'condition' column

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
out <- setDT(df1)[,  .(Duration = max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)),
        .(Date = as.IDate(timestamp),
    grp = rleid(condition), condition)
     ][as.logical(condition)][, .(Duration = sum(Duration)), .(Date)]

out[, Duration := seconds_to_period(Duration)][]
#       Date   Duration
#1: 2020-01-01 5H 52M 35S
#2: 2020-01-02  1H 8M 17S
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1577891413, 1577891483, 
    1577891685, 1577895782, 1577896394, 1577913013, 1577921652, 1577927433, 
    1577937896, 1577978085, 1577982182, 1577982794, 1577999413), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), condition = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is what I am ding right now. But I am not getting the expected output

Comment: @VictorJohnzon can you please update with your code in the post

Comment: @VictorJohnzon in your post, it says, you are only groupiing by `rleid` of condition to get the difference, then later you are taking the sum.  I am doing the grouping by 'Date' and 'rleid

Comment: But it should be the sum of differences between these : `2020-01-01 11:33:14` and  `2020-01-01 10:11:23` , `2020-01-01 23:59:59` and `2020-01-01 18:34:12`

Comment: @VictorJohnzon I don't have 23:59:59 in my dataset

Comment: Yes, that is what I was saying, if a condition is exceeding to next day, then we need to calculate the duration til 23:59:59 for first day and from 00:00:00 for second day and output it as two different days data

Comment: @VictorJohnzon here, is what i have  `2020-01-01 23:04:56         1` how is this exceeding the 23:59:59

Comment: 2020-01-01 18:34:12 1
    2020-01-01 20:10:33 1
    2020-01-01 23:04:56 1
    2020-01-02 10:14:45 1
    2020-01-02 11:23:02 1


Here you can see right, the condition is happening on two different days. I need to do a split at 00:00:00

Comment: @VictorJohnzon Isn't the `as.Date` doing the split for each day?

Comment: no i am actually taking as.Date(min(timestamp)). Now I am trying to rewrite this by splitting

Comment: @VictorJohnzon iif you check my code, I am grouping by 'Date' here `Date = as.IDate(timestamp)` which stripss of the time stamp

Comment: @VictorJohnzon, your logic is not clear to me.  The other answer is also getting the same output.